# High and Low Values sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query to display the maximum and minimum values from a table called products according to a date from another table called pro_details.The query should display the most purchased products of that particular date as well as the least product purchased. However, the query does not show any record for a given month even when the actual date is exist!

```
SELECT 
    Prod.delivered, MIN(quality) Low, MAX(quality) High 
FROM 
    pro_details prod, products pro
WHERE 
    pro.ord = pro.ord
    AND Prod.delivered = TO_DATE('12-2015','mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY  
    Prod.delivered
ORDER BY  
    Prod.delivered DESC;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The DBMS I am using is Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a 'd' near where clause and also have to convert delivered field to 'mm-yyyy' string format. 
Try this:

```
SELECT Prod.delivered, MIN(quality) Low, MAX(quality) High 
FROM pro_details prod, products pro
WHERE prod.ord = pro.ord
AND  TO_CHAR(Prod.delivered,'mm-yyyy') = '12-2015'
GROUP BY  Prod.delivered
ORDER BY Prod.delivered DESC;
```

Revised Query:

```
SELECT pro.ord, quality
from pro_details prod, products pro
where prod.ord = pro.ord
AND TO_CHAR(Prod.delivered,'mm-yyyy') = '12-2015'
GROUP BY pro.ord, quality
having quality=min(quality) or quality=max(quality)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Dan. My Intention is to show the most popular product sold a giving month and the least one sold in the same month.

Comment: @Max I don't think the original query can figure out your intention.  I am revising another query for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

SQL date comparisons are **exact**. If you only include a month and year in a date, the comparison assumes you meant to use zeroes for all of the remaining components in a DateTime value. You're making an exact comparison for records that are dated only for the first instant of the month.

If you want the entire month, you need to check the whole range, from the start of the month to the end of the month:

```
SELECT Prod.delivered, MIN(quality) Low, MAX(quality) High 
FROM pro_details prod, products pro
WHERE pro.ord = pro.ord
  AND  Prod.delivered >= TO_DATE('12-2015','mm-yyyy')
  AND  Prod.delivered <  TO_DATE('01-2016','mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY  Prod.delivered
ORDER BY Prod.delivered DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. My Intention is to show the most popular product sold a giving month and the least one sold in the same month. Let say I sold 10 products  8 with a product number of 555 and only two of a product with number 111! How do I show the results as the most sold is 555 and the number of sale 8 while 111 with only 2 as number of sales